# Timestamping PDF with Itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, timestamp, itext, digital-signature

I have a problem during timestamping PDF file with Itextsharp and MakeSignature.SignDetached method.

- My certs are stored on a Luna HSM.
- itextsharp ver:5.5.11
- PkcsInterop.PDF ver: 1.3.0

Without timestamp, belowed code is working perfectly. When i want to sign with timestamp an exception is thrown  :

> The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout.

And Fiddler gives me that response header :

> HTTP/1.1 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure Date: Mon, 30 Apr 2018 11:28:57
>   GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Connection: close
>   Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate Timestamp: 14:28:57.430
>   [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: **The server did not return a complete
>   response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes**.

```
        public void SignPDF(byte[] pdf, SignData signData) //signData: my custom class, it's about sign image,location,size
    {
        string timeStampServer = "http://xxxxxxxx";
        string timeStampUser = "xxxx";
        string timeStampPass = "xxxx";

        string cryptokiDLL = @"C:\Program Files\SafeNet\LunaClient\cryptoki.dll";
        string tokenLabel = "xxx";
        string pin = "xxxx";
        string primaryKeyLabel = "xxxxx";
        string certsDir = @"C:\CERTs";

        iTextSharp.text.Image signImg = null;
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle signRec = null;
        byte[] signedPDF = null;
        string hash = null;

        try
        {

            HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithm.SHA256;
            Pkcs11RsaSignature pkcs11RsaSignature = new Pkcs11RsaSignature(cryptokiDLL, null, tokenLabel, pin, primaryKeyLabel, null, hashAlgorithm);
            byte[] signingCertificate = pkcs11RsaSignature.GetSigningCertificate();//1460 
            List<byte[]> otherCertificates = new List<byte[]>();
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(certsDir))
                otherCertificates.Add(File.ReadAllBytes(file));
            var chain = CertUtils.BuildCertPath(signingCertificate, otherCertificates).ToList();

            ITSAClient tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(timeStampServer, timeStampUser, timeStampPass);

            IOcspClient ocspClient = new OcspClientBouncyCastle();

            List<ICrlClient> crlList = new List<ICrlClient>();
            crlList.Add(new CrlClientOnline(chain));

            using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf))
            {
                using (MemoryStream msPDFfinal = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, msPDFfinal, '\0'))
                    {
                        PdfWriter writer = pdfStamper.Writer;
                        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;

                        byte[] signImgBinary = signData.ImzaBinary;
                        int x = signData.X;
                        int y = signData.Y;
                        int scale = signData.Scale;
                        int pageNum = signData.PageNum;

                        signImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(signImgBinary);
                        signImg.ScalePercent(scale);

                        float imgX = (float)x;
                        float imgY = (float)y;
                        float scaledW = signImg.ScaledWidth;
                        float scaledH = signImg.ScaledHeight;

                        signRec = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(imgX, imgY, imgX + scaledW, imgY + scaledH);

                        appearance.Layer2Text = " ";
                        appearance.Image = signImg;
                        appearance.SetVisibleSignature(signRec, pageNum, "SIG");

                        //without timestamp, it is signing the pdf. Everything is ok.
                        //MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pkcs11RsaSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);

                        //it returns 504 error, no server response
                        MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, pkcs11RsaSignature, chain, crlList, ocspClient, tsaClient, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);
                    }

                    signedPDF = msPDFfinal.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

and finally, according to this link
[what is wrong with godaddy's timestamp server and itextsharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717034/what-is-wrong-with-godaddys-timestamp-server-and-itextsharp)
i have added user-agent and http protocol headers but nothing is changed, still getting error.

```
 protected internal virtual byte[] GetTSAResponse(byte[] requestBytes) {
            HttpWebRequest con = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(tsaURL);
            con.UserAgent = "itextsharp";
            con.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
            con.ContentLength = requestBytes.Length;
            con.ContentType = "application/timestamp-query";
            con.Method = "POST";
            con.KeepAlive = true;
            if ((tsaUsername != null) && !tsaUsername.Equals("") ) {
                string authInfo = tsaUsername + ":" + tsaPassword;
                authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo), Base64FormattingOptions.None);
                con.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
            }
            Stream outp = con.GetRequestStream();
            outp.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
            outp.Close();
```

Comment: Your problem is most likely related to the particular TSA service you are using but sadly I cannot test it because I don't have its URL and your credentials. So before I can try to answer your question I need to ask you to use [TimeStampClient](https://github.com/disig/TimeStampClient/) application to request timestamp from that service and let me know if it works.

Comment: Inspect your TCP traffic (e.g. with Wireshark). What are the HTTP headers of your request?.